# How can I add a Task dependency on a task from another plugin to my SBT plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I am writing a Plugin for SBT that will generate the configuration files needed to create an Azure Function from a Scala program. My efforts are on github (https://github.com/code-star/sbt-azure-functions-plugin/tree/develop), and as can be read in the readme, I want to automatically trigger the `assembly` task whenever the user issues `sbt azfunCreateZipFile`.

Users of my plugin, can be achieve this by adding the following line to their `build.sbt`:

```
azfunCreateZipFile := (azfunCreateZipFile dependsOn assembly).value
```

I would like that task wiring to be already included in my plugin definition. How can I do this?

I know Tasks can be made dependent on other Tasks by using `otherTask.value` in the task definition, so I tried adding such a line to the `azfunCreateZipFile` task definition (see `./plugin/src/main/scala/sbtazurefunctions/AzureFunctions.scala`):

```
azfunGenerateFunctionJsons := {
  // depend on assembly step
  val _ = assembly.value
  ... <actual task definition code>
  azfunTargetFolder.value
}
```

But then I get an error that assembly is not found:

```
[IJ]sbt:root> compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/jml/work/scala/azure/sbt-azure-functions- plugin/plugin/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes ...
[error] /home/jml/work/scala/azure/sbt-azure-functions-plugin/plugin/src/main/scala/sbtazurefunctions/AzureFunctions.scala:113:15: not found: value assembly
[error]       val _ = assembly.value
[error]               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (plugin / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 3, 2021, 4:41:56 PM
[IJ]sbt:root>
```

I have tried many imports, but none were successful:

```
import sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin._ (and variations using AssemblyKeys and the AutoImport object)
import sbt.Keys._
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This other SO answer ([How can I use an sbt plugin as a dependency in a multi-project build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482604/how-can-i-use-an-sbt-plugin-as-a-dependency-in-a-multi-project-build)) finally put me on the right track, as it shows the use of `libraryDependencies += Defaults.sbtPluginExtra`, so thanks @michael-zajac.

I ended up adding the assembly dependency like this:

```
lazy val plugin = (project in file("plugin"))
  .enablePlugins(SbtPlugin)
  .settings(
    ...<other settings>...,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-sbt" %% "scripted-plugin" % sbtVersion.value,
      Defaults.sbtPluginExtra("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10", "1.0", "2.12")
    ),
    ...
```

Even better:

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-sbt" %% "scripted-plugin" % sbtVersion.value
    ),
    addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10"),
```